# `\frac` automatically render the most beautiful variation

Tags: typography

Often, `a/b` and `\frac{a}{b}` are semantically the same.

However, using one over the other is a typographical choice.

So it got me thinking, as a typographical choice, shouldn't TEX engine make that choice for me, instead of me writing it?

I'm thinking of some function `\f{a}{b}` that depend on the layout, either expand to `a/b` or `\frac{a}{b}`.

Is there something like this?

Comment: what kind of layout you want the macro to depends on?

Comment: Some random comments: (1) "typographical choice" at least sometimes depends on personal senses of aesthetic, so may not be universal (2) `\frac` already do that to some degree, vis-a-vis the different outputs in in-line versus displayed math (3) back to "typographical choice", there's also the option of "nice" version of `a/b` such as provided by the `xfrac` package.

Comment: I think `nath` package does support this, but breaks a few other things.

Comment: Use `\mathchoice`.